Yaskawa robot moveit2 demo.launch.py error
Setup:
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
ROS2 humble
Issue:
I've been trying to follow this tutorial https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/examples/setup_assistant/setup_assistant_tutorial.html to set up a yaskawa robot arm https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/motoman/tree/ros2/motoman_gp8_support

But when I run the demo.launch.py I only get errors. I'm not sure if I'm missing something or I should also prepare a description package for the robot arm as well
Log:
$ ros2 launch motoman_gp8_moveit_config demo.launch.py --debug
[DEBUG] [launch.launch_context]: emitting event synchronously: 'launch.events.IncludeLaunchDescription'
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/ivan/.ros/log/2024-04-24-12-09-05-559370-ivan-Zephyrus-G16-90253
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to DEBUG
[DEBUG] [launch]: processing event: '<launch.events.include_launch_description.IncludeLaunchDescription object at 0x73800797eef0>'
[DEBUG] [launch]: processing event: '<launch.events.include_launch_description.IncludeLaunchDescription object at 0x73800797eef0>' ✓ '<launch.event_handlers.on_include_launch_description.OnIncludeLaunchDescription object at 0x7380077cb340>'
Using load_yaml() directly is deprecated. Use xacro.load_yaml() instead.
Using load_yaml() directly is deprecated. Use xacro.load_yaml() instead.
Using load_yaml() directly is deprecated. Use xacro.load_yaml() instead.
Using load_yaml() directly is deprecated. Use xacro.load_yaml() instead.
Using load_yaml() directly is deprecated. Use xacro.load_yaml() instead.
Using load_yaml() directly is deprecated. Use xacro.load_yaml() instead.
Using load_yaml() directly is deprecated. Use xacro.load_yaml() instead.
Using load_yaml() directly is deprecated. Use xacro.load_yaml() instead.
Using load_yaml() directly is deprecated. Use xacro.load_yaml() instead.
Using load_yaml() directly is deprecated. Use xacro.load_yaml() instead.
Executing <Task finished name='Task-2' coro=<LaunchService._process_one_event() done, defined at /opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py:228> exception=TypeError("Expected 'value' to be one of [<class 'float'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'bool'>, <class 'bytes'>], but got '()' of type '<class 'tuple'>'") created at /opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py:318> took 0.457 seconds
[DEBUG] [launch]: An exception was raised in an async action/event
[DEBUG] [launch]: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py", line 336, in run_async
    raise completed_tasks_exceptions[0]
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py", line 230, in _process_one_event
    await self.__process_event(next_event)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py", line 250, in __process_event
    visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(entity, self.__context))
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
  [Previous line repeated 3 more times]
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 38, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    sub_entities = entity.visit(context)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/action.py", line 108, in visit
    return self.execute(context)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch_ros/actions/node.py", line 490, in execute
    self._perform_substitutions(context)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch_ros/actions/node.py", line 445, in _perform_substitutions
    evaluated_parameters = evaluate_parameters(context, self.__parameters)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch_ros/utilities/evaluate_parameters.py", line 164, in evaluate_parameters
    output_params.append(evaluate_parameter_dict(context, param))
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch_ros/utilities/evaluate_parameters.py", line 136, in evaluate_parameter_dict
    ensure_argument_type(value, (float, int, str, bool, bytes), 'value')
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/launch/utilities/ensure_argument_type_impl.py", line 73, in ensure_argument_type
    raise TypeError(error_msg_template.format(
TypeError: Expected 'value' to be one of [<class 'float'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'bool'>, <class 'bytes'>], but got '()' of type '<class 'tuple'>'

[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): Expected 'value' to be one of [<class 'float'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'bool'>, <class 'bytes'>], but got '()' of type '<class 'tuple'>'
[DEBUG] [launch.launch_context]: emitting event: 'launch.events.Shutdown'
[DEBUG] [launch]: processing event: '<launch.events.shutdown.Shutdown object at 0x7380077ca890>'
[DEBUG] [launch]: processing event: '<launch.events.shutdown.Shutdown object at 0x7380077ca890>' ✓ '<launch.event_handlers.on_shutdown.OnShutdown object at 0x738007ba85b0>'
[DEBUG] [launch]: processing event: '<launch.events.shutdown.Shutdown object at 0x7380077ca890>' ✓ '<launch.event_handlers.on_shutdown.OnShutdown object at 0x7380060fdd20>'
[DEBUG] [launch]: processing event: '<launch.events.shutdown.Shutdown object at 0x7380077ca890>' ✓ '<launch.event_handlers.on_shutdown.OnShutdown object at 0x7380077cab00>'
```

